# HTML Calendar Appearing Under Footer

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I've created an HTML Calendar for my django app. However when I add it to one of my templates it adds it underneath my footer. I'm not understanding why this would happen.

```html
{% extends "bf_app/app_bases/app_base.html" %}

{% block main %}
    {% include "bf_app/overviews/overview_nav.html" %}
    <div class="flex justify-between mx-10">
        <a href="{% url 'calendar_overview_context' previous_year previous_month %}">< {{ previous_month_name }}</a>
        <a href="{% url 'calendar_overview_context' next_year next_month %}">{{ next_month_name }} ></a>
    </div>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 px-4">
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-left">Transaction</th>
                <th class="text-left">Amount</th>
                <th class="text-left">Date</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            {% for transaction, tally in monthly_budget.items %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ transaction }}</td>
                    <td class="{% if tally|last == "IN" %}text-green-700{% else %}text-red-700{% endif %}">
                        {{ tally|first|floatformat:2 }}
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ transaction.next_date|date:"D, d M, Y" }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ calendar }}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

I pretty much followed this tutorial:
https://www.huiwenteo.com/normal/2018/07/24/django-calendar.html

Is there something I'm missing? This to my understanding should be above the footer like everything else I've created.

EDIT:

It seems to be the "mark_safe" module causing the issue. I've tried using `{{ calendar|safe }}` and this also creates the same issue.

*with safe*
[image: calendar with safe]

*without safe*
[image]

Comment: Where did you placed your footer in `"bf_app/app_bases/app_base.html"` provide that

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, using huiwenteo calendar tutorial.

This weird behavior is making Calendar class, more specific the formatmonth method. Because its returning calendar table, without closing html  tag. So in your cal/utils.py file you should add `cal += f'</table>\n'` to formatmonth method, before returning calendar.

Here is example, which worked for me.

```
def formatmonth(self, ....):
        events = Event.objects.filter(....)

        cal = f'<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">\n'
        cal += f'{self.formatmonthname(self.year, self.month, withyear=withyear)}\n'
        cal += f'{self.formatweekheader()}\n'
        for week in self.monthdays2calendar(self.year, self.month):
            cal += f'{self.formatweek(week, events)}\n'
        cal += f'</table>\n'
        return cal
```